# Need to POST a single form to two different pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post a single form to two pages. The first page is loacally hosted and other one is a remote page which need to be redirected after posting to first page. I can use jquery to post the form but have no idea how to post to the remote server's file.

My form is like:

```
<form method ='POST' action='https://remotewebsite.com/api/step1.asp' id='payment_form' class='form-horizontal' >
    <div class='form-body'>
        <input type='hidden' name='group' value='$net_amount'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='type' value='$payment_type' />

        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <button type='button' class='btn default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>
            <input type='button' id='pay' name='pay' value='pay' class='btn green' />                       
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

I can use jquery to post it to my other page say "process.php" but couldn't find any way to submit the form again to the url https://remotewebsite.com/api/step1.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser's default action of submitting 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data=$("#payment_form").serialize(),
                data: data,
                dataType: "html",
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to POST to your `process.php` script as you currently are.

Then after you've finished processing, fire off a `cURL` POST request to the remote server (from your `process.php` script. If you Google for `PHP curl post request` you should find a load of articles telling you how to do so, e.g: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: It's interesting but I need to redirect the current page after making POST to process.php. The second page (https://remotewebsite.com/api/step1.asp) is itself a form which needed to be filled later.

Comment: There's no reason why you cannot redirect after posting to `process.php`, you can use `window.location` in JS for that. What I don't understand is what this second form is... are you saying you want to populate it's fields?

Answer (score 1):

how about just simply duplicate $.ajax?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=button]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser's default action of submitting 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data=$("#payment_form").serialize(),
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://remotewebsite.com/api/step1.asp",
            data=$("#payment_form").serialize(),
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's not possible by simply adding $.ajax twice.